# postgres 16 oddment on unary 'not' function

Tags: postgresql

In short, what does this mean?

```
mydb=# select version();
                                                            version                                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 16.1 (Homebrew) 

mydb=# select not null = null not;
 not 
-----
 
(1 row)

mydb=# select not null = not null not;
 not 
-----
 
(1 row)


mydb=# select not null = not not null not;
 not 
-----
 
(1 row)
```

Not a syntax error.

Comment: its giving a name to the column

Comment: Don't use a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `not` as column alias, even less after omitting the `AS` keyword. The rest is not so confusing.

Comment: If this output made you think you're seeing the result above the dashes: that's the column name, and the empty line below it is supposed to be the `null` you got from the expression. Set `null` to be represented by something else than the default empty string: [`\pset null '(null)'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-PSET-NULL) and strap `AS "is_something"` to bool columns for clarity. To compare `null`, use [`is not distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NOT` in two ways here:

1. as a [logical operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html)
2. as a [column alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS)

If you look at the table of the [precedence of operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), you will see that your three queries translate to

```
SELECT NOT (NULL = NULL) AS null;

SELECT NOT (NULL = (NOT NULL)) AS null;

SELECT NOT (NULL = (NOT (NOT NULL))) AS null;
```

Since NULL is the undefined value, it is undefined whether the result is TRUE or FALSE, hence the result it NULL.

Comment: Was looking so close I totally missed I was creating a column alias; assumed `AS` had to be there for that but no.